# Synonym for "sure" and "yes please"

Tags: slang, formality, conversation

When somebody suggests me something (maybe offering me something, or suggesting me for a proposal/plan), and I would like to show my agreement/approval for that. Instead of just saying "sure" or "yes please", what are the other common options to express that?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked a thesaurus?

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sure?s=t                    
https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/how-agree-english           
And I've also looked at some other similar links, but they are not what I am looking for. Hope that explains.

Comment: This site is not meant to provide lists—unless it is only a few words or phrases that specifically match where others don't. In addition to the ten phrases given in the one answer so far, I'm sure there are that many again or more that could be thought of. You need to provide criteria for your question that serve to eliminate all of the "wrong" answers and clearly point to a "correct" one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will say that this question asks about two phrases.  One is polite, the other is neutral, so please take the below as neutral, not as particularly polite.

"Sounds good"

"Sounds good to me"

"Sounds like a plan"

"Okay, let's do it"

"Absolutely!" (in response to would you like *something*?)

"Okay, when should we get started?"

"I'm in."

"Count me in!"

"I agree."

"I concur."

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think "sounds like a plan" is especially good for agreeing on a plan.

Comment: "I concur", would be used only if you're giving your expert agreement to another's opinion.  For example, if one doctor says, "I think he has appendicitis."  Another doctor might say, "I concur with your diagnosis."  This is strictly for *expert* opinions/agreement.

Comment: Thanks. It is also what I am looking for. That's better than just saying "I agree" in that scenario.